# Dojo mix two files

Tags: javascript, web, dojo

I have one file with defined module like:

```
    define([
        "xstyle/css!./less/layout.less", 
        "dojo", "dojo/parser", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/store/Observable", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/on", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/sniff", "dojo/keys", "dojo/string", "dojo/topic", "dojo/date/locale", "dojo/date/stamp", "dojo/date", "dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/number", "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dijit", "dijit/PopupMenuItem", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/form/Select", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
        "dojox/layout/TableContainer", 
        "dgrid/editor", "dgrid/Keyboard", "dgrid/selector"
       ],
        function(
            less, 
            dojo, parser, MemoryStore, domStyle, domConstruct, Observable, declare, query, domAttr, on, xhr, has, keys, string, topic, localeDate, stamp, dojoDate, JsonRest, dojoNumber, lang,
            dijit, PopupMenuItem, Menu, MenuItem, Select, Dialog, ContentPane, Toolbar, Button, TextBox, FilteringSelect,
            TableContainer, 
            editor, Keyboard, selector
            ) {

            function createWidgetSpecified(root, collectionsToolbar){
                ...
            }

            function getCollectionGrid(root, fieldCode, style){
                ....
            }

            function filterDocumentTypeFieldsForNonByte(documentData){
                .....
            }

            ...


            return declare(Dialog, {
                ...,
                ...,
                constructor: function(args){
                  lang.mixin(this, args);
                },
                createIssuerInfo: function(issuerData){
                    ...
                },
                createMatcher: function(root){
                    ...
                },
                ...
            });
        });
```

and I want to mix with another.
For me important think is to:
replace or add new function (not declared in class). For example, I'want to replace createWidgetSpecified with its new version, and add two more function like: startSave, startDelete. How can I do this ?

I dind't mention it that those functions only known in runtime. I mean that module with I defined, is created with parameter type = 26. And I want to load that function from file : ../js/fortype/26/document.js for type 26

like:
var moduleObject = new Module({type:26});
And I want to dynamicly load functions for type 26

Comment: So if I'm reading your question correctly, you want to run your app, then at some point require and define an instance of a module based on some index that you have which maps specific modules by an id, like your '26' example?

Answer (score 0):

In File A :

```
define([
    ..., 
    "./FileB"
], function (
    ..., FileB) {

   return declare([otherMixins, FileB], {
       // functions in File A   
   });
});
```

In File B:

```
define([
    ...
], function (
    ...) {

   return declare([], {
       // functions in File B   
   });
});
```

Comment: I didn't mention it that, the functions that I want to load are known only in runtime. And they could exist in a file calld: ../js/function/fortype/24/documents.js  -- this file is generated for type with id 24